# Docker installing yarn at root causing tsc rootDir error

Tags: typescript, docker, yarnpkg

I have a node project that is a simple server hello world. Running locally this all compiles fine and runs perfectly. When inside Docker however a /opt/yarn-v1.21.1 folder is created which causes a rootDir error:

```
error TS6059: File '/opt/yarn-v1.21.1/bin/yarn.js' is not under 'rootDir' '/opt/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:13.8.0-alpine

WORKDIR /opt

COPY package*.json ./
COPY tsconfig*.json ./

RUN npm i --quiet
```

tsconfig

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",                          
        "module": "commonjs",                    
        "lib": ["es6"],                     
        "allowJs": true,
        "outDir": "dist",                          
        "rootDir": "src",
        "strict": true,         
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
    },
}
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "test-api",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "tsc",
        "start:dev": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"nodemon dist/app.js\""
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/node": "^13.7.0",
        "concurrently": "^5.1.0",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.2",
        "typescript": "^3.7.5"
    }
}
```

Any insights would be much appreciated why running this through docker would differ. The only assumption I leapt to was that yarn was already installed on my system but it is installed within the image by default.

It is worth mentioning that changing the rootDir from `/src` to `./` does solve the error but the output in the disc folder then becomes:

```
dist
  src
    app.js
  yarn-v1.21.1
```

Instead of:

```
dist
  app.js
```

Comment: Can you change your Dockerfile: `WORKDIR /opt` to `WORKDIR /app`? Does that solve your issue?

Comment: That looks to have sorted it @Mihai, is there a reasoning behind this?

Comment: The Dockerfile you show contains neither any Typescript source files nor a `CMD` to say how to run the container when it starts up.  Is what you have here a [mcve]; will just running `docker build` here demonstrate this issue?

Comment: I replied in the answer below. Let me know if that is not clear enough.

Comment: @DavidMaze Mihai sussed it, thanks for looking though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your WORKDIR command in Dockerfile to the following:

```
WORKDIR /app
```

The base image has yarn already installed in the /opt directory. When you add your app as well in the /opt folder, then it thinks that the folder yarn-1.21.1 is also part of your application, hence the error. Probably you could also use `WORKDIR /opt/app` if you really want your app under /opt.

Comment: Thanks for this, really appreciate it. Will make a note not to use the /opt dir in future!